# Google Maps for Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic, google

I am looking to integrate a Google Maps into the woocommerce checkout page, wherein, the customer, while checking out has to select his/her Google Maps location, it gets stored for each order and then it can be seen in the edit order page of the wordpress backend. Any ideas on how to do this or plugins that can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking for a similar thing at the moment and am investigating 2 different plugins:

- https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-checkout-location-picker/6811588
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/checkout-address-sugessions-for-woocommerce/

I will be trying out the second plugin first, as it is free. Hope that helps

(UPDATE) Neither of the above plugins did the job unfortunately, I would not recommend

Comment: None of the above plugins work and I would not recommend either of them at this time

Comment: Can you please edit your answer with relevant code that would resolve this question? Ideally, avoid external links. Thanks.

Comment: @LouisvanderWalt maybe this would help: https://wordpress.org/plugins/map-location-picker-at-checkout-for-woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

I created such a thing a while back. Basically, you need to integrate the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview) into the checkout page and save the location details with the order metadata using the `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` hook. That way you'd be able to display it on the order details page as well as the user account page.

You can check out the plugin/source code here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/map-location-picker-at-checkout-for-woocommerce